# orthogonalization of a matrix to another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have an equation $V^T*M*V=E$ so I need to perform an operation on $V$ say $F(V)=V'$ which leads to $V'^T*M*V'=I$ in which $I$ is identity matrix. what is that operation in linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

if $V,M,E$ are all square matrices and $E$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix you could Cholesky decompose $E = LL^T$ and thus with $L$ invertible this would give
$$
V^T M V = E
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
V^T M V = LL^T
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
L^{-1} V^T M V L^{-T} = I\\
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
(L^{-T})^T V^T M V L^{-T} = I
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
(V L^{-T})^T M (V L^{-T}) = I
\quad\Longleftrightarrow:\quad
(V^\prime)^T M V^\prime = I
$$