# Orthogonalise a matrix with respect to another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I need to do a particular operation and I am not able to find a name or some ideas to make the operation happen.

I have a matrix $F_s \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n_s}$. I do an Singular value decomposition on it to get the left singular vectors $F_s \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

Here $F_u^T * F_u = I$. I want to now Orthogonalise this $F_u$ with respect to $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ i.e., $F_u^T Q F_u = I$.

A very similar question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384433/orthogonalization-of-a-matrix-to-another-matrix), but no proper response is obtained.

I am looking for the process I need to do to orthogonalize a matrix $F_u$ with respect to another matrix $Q$. I looked at Generalised SVD and Weighted SVD, but they dont fit with this idea.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, $Q$ is some kind of positive definite matrix.

Perform a Cholesky decomposition to get $Q = U^TU$.  We then have
$$
F_u^TQF_u = I \iff (UF_u)^T(UF_u) = I
$$
That is, your process is equivalent to "orthogonalising" $UF_u$.

Comment: What you are saying is shocking! Every Positive definite matrix when pre-multiplied by $F_u^T$ and post multiplied by F_u of any shape, should give 'I' at any cost!. I think there is something missing. I tried on a positive definite matrix(A = Q @ Q.T), where Q is a random square matrix. IT DIDNT WORK! What could be wrong, This is puzzling. Oh wait! you basically just said A.T @ A = I. This is not true for every positive definite matrix.

Comment: It seems to me like you misunderstood what I said. I also am not totally sure what you're saying in your comment

Comment: Ok! Let me clarify. You have said that $F_u^T Q F_U = I $ if $Q$ is a positive definite matrix. This is wrong! I tried it with a positive definite  IT DOESNT WORK. Your mistake I think is suggesting that $(U F_u )^T (U F_u) = I $. This is not true. It's a transpose not an inverse! Further, going by your conclusion it would mean that if pre multiply any positive definite matrix with $F^T$ and premultiple with F, it would give I. THIS IS not true!

Comment: That is not what I said

Comment: Please clarify!

Comment: I am saying that $F_u^TQF_u = I$ exactly when (i.e. for exactly the same $F_u$'s that satisfy) $UF_u$ is an orthogonal matrix.